# Does C# enforce that an `unmanaged` type is "blittable"?

Tags: c#, interop, specifications, unmanaged, type-constraints

I'm wondering if [C# 7.3's Unmanaged type constraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/unmanaged-types) provides language support for enforcing that a type is blittable.  According to [Blittable and Non-Blittable types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/blittable-and-non-blittable-types) correctly making platform invoke calls requires asserting that the return type is blittable:

> Structures that are returned from platform invoke calls must be blittable types. Platform invoke does not support non-blittable structures as return types.

The official documentation doesn't seem to state anywhere that C# enforces that an `unmanaged` type is "blittable", however.  I'm apprehensive about assuming so because there is evidence that, at one time at least, whether a type is "blittable" could only be determined empirically.

#### Unmanaged type constraint documentation

[The C# 7.3 "Unmanaged type constraint" proposal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-7.3/blittable) includes the following:

> The unmanaged constraint feature will give language enforcement to the class of types known as "unmanaged types" in the C# language spec. ...
>
> ...
>
> **Blittable vs. Unmanaged**
>
> The F# language has a very similar feature which uses the keyword unmanaged. The blittable name comes from the use in Midori. May want to look to precedence here and use unmanaged instead.
>
> Resolution The language decide to use unmanaged
>
> ...

The phrase "unmanaged types" here seems to refer to "*unmanaged_type*" defined in [Unsafe code - Pointer Types of the draft C# 6 specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/unsafe-code#pointer-types) (I did not find a similar reference in [the C# 5 ECMA standard](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications-and-standards/standards/ecma-334/)).  *unmanaged_type* is defined as follows:

> An unmanaged_type is any type that isn't a *reference_type* or constructed type, and doesn't contain *reference_type* or constructed type fields at any level of nesting. In other words, an *unmanaged_type* is one of the following:
>
> - `sbyte`, `byte`, `short`, `ushort`, `int`, `uint`, `long`, `ulong`, `char`, `float`, `double`, `decimal`, or `bool`.
> - Any *enum_type*.
> - Any *pointer_type*.
> - Any user-defined *struct_type* that is not a constructed type and contains fields of *unmanaged_types* only.

I haven't found C# 7.3's `unmanaged` type constraint mentioned in the [interop marshaling documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/interop-marshaling); that documentation seems to predate that feature.

#### Blittable type documentation

[Blittable and Non-blittable Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/blittable-and-non-blittable-types) states that the following are blittable:

- `System.Byte`, `System.SByte`, `System.Int16`, `System.UInt16`, `System.Int32`, `System.UInt32`, `System.Int64`, `System.UInt64`, `System.IntPtr`, `System.UIntPtr`, `System.Single`, `System.Double`
- One-dimensional arrays of blittable types, such as an array of integers. However, a type that contains a variable array of blittable types is not itself blittable.
- Formatted value types that contain only blittable types (and classes if they are marshaled as formatted types). For more information about formatted value types, see Default marshaling for value types.

#### Is every `unmanaged` type "Blittable"?

At first I thought that the above definitions imply that every `unmanaged` type is "blittable".  But I haven't found any official documentation that comes right out and states that.  The closest I have found is [this reply](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/187#issuecomment-283401703) from (as I understand the timeline) before the `unmanaged` type constraint feature was implemented:

> > How is this related to Blittable Types in Interop Marshaling? The same? or similar but bit different?
>
> It's the same.

That seems like evidence in the affirmative, but it's also rather weak evidence upon which to base design decisions.  (FWIW, that exchange could also by interpreted as the meaning that all "blittable" types are `unmanaged` which seems less likely to be true.)

And then there's the matter of `bool` which isn't "blittable" and `System.Boolean` which is `unmanaged` according to the documentation.  That complication [is acknowledged but not directly addressed for the interop marshaler in the original proposal.](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/187#issuecomment-284054821)

#### Why I'm apprehensive about this

I was not an active C# developer while the history of this seems to have unfolded and there are surely clues I've missed.  Of the clues I have found, many are in the negative; there seems to have been a time when the implementation of P/Invoke resisted a total intensional definition distinguishing between blittable and non-blittable types.  In other words, there were at least some versions of C# where it was non-trivial (or perhaps not possible) to confirm *a priori* whether the interop marshaler considered a type to be blittable.  Or at least it seems that way.  For example, [Hans Passant wrote in 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33817457/1404637)

> There is no easy way to find out if a type is blittable, other than it not working correctly or by using the debugger and compare pointer values.

Another clue is that each of the approaches to the answers in [The fastest way to check if a type is blittable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10574645/1404637) (asked in 2012) seem to be empirical.  This seems like further evidence in the negative.

I suppose it could be that all `unmanaged` types are "blittable" but not all "blittable" types are `unmanaged`.  But that's just speculation on my part.

Comment: You may ask this question in [original `blittable`/`unmanaged` constraint proposal](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/187)

Comment: No, simplest counter-example is a struct with a bool field.  Never blittable, okay to meet the constraint.  It just doesn't make sense to mix the concepts, for one you'd never consider a generic type in pinvoke.

Answer (score 1):

[Hans Passant confirmed the answer in the negative.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65833341/does-c-sharp-enforce-that-an-unmanaged-type-is-blittable#comment116401977_65833341)

> No, simplest counter-example is a struct with a bool field. Never blittable, okay to meet the constraint...

This seems to be a sufficient basis upon which to conclude that the answer is "no".

The second part of Hans' answer is, I think, more interesting:

> It just doesn't make sense to mix the concepts...

This is counter to how I interpreted other opinions which seemed to suggest that `unmanaged` and "blittable" are "the same".  I didn't find any elaboration of Hans' opinion that it doesn't make sense to mix the concept of `unmanaged` and "blittable". But I have formed an opinion of my own.

#### A Definition for "blittable"

The term "blittable" seems to mean slightly different things to different people and in different contexts ([example 1](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/187#issuecomment-283369430), [2](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/187#issuecomment-283471709)).  I'll use the following definition from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/native-interop/best-practices) for the remainder of this answer:

> Blittable types are types that have the same bit-level representation in managed and native code. As such they do not need to be converted to another format to be marshaled to and from native code...

#### Whether a type is "blittable" depends on the particulars of the counterpart code.

By the above definition whether a type is "blittable" depends on whether the counterpart code with which you are exchanging data interprets the bits of a type in the same manner as your code.  `bool` and `BOOL` provide a good example:

- The [CLI specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm) contains a bitwise definition of the "Boolean data type" as follows:

  - occupies 1 byte in memory
  - a bit pattern with any one or more bits set denotes true
  - a bit pattern of all zeros denotes a value of false
- The [Win32 API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/windows-data-types) defines `BOOL` as an `int` and [MSVC's `int`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/data-type-ranges?view=msvc-160) is 32 bits wide.
- .Net/.Net - Because of the CLI's bitwise definition of the boolean data type, writing the bits of a `bool` from .Net to, for example, a file and reading those same bits as a `bool` requires no conversion; any .Net program will interpret the bits of such a boolean in the same manner.
- .Net/win32 - Because of the size discrepancy between the bitwise representation of .Net `bool` and win32's `BOOL` exchanging booleans between those domains requires conversion. Without conversion, win32 APIs emitting `BOOL` could set only bits in the most significant 24 bits to convey true and .Net may well interpret that as `bool` false.

#### Summary

From the perspective of C#, whether a type is blittable depends on whether the counterpart code happens to interpret the bits representing that type in the same way.  That will vary depending on the counterparty.  In the case of .Net exchanging data with a .Net counterparty, `unmanaged` provides a constraint that guarantees that the bits representing the type will be correctly interpreted by the two parties.

For counterparties other than .Net, no such similar language constraints currently exist.  And I wouldn't expect such a constraint to exist in C#; the counterparties are many and their interpretation of the bits representating their types are surely defined in a manner that the C# specification cannot rely upon.

Comment: Whether a managed type is blittable does NOT depend on the native counterpart. The term "blittable" relates to if the CLR will decide to blit instances of the type or not, not  whether it *should* blit them or not. For example, the bool field in a type can still be blittable if the MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1) attribute is applied to it. Of course if the counterpart in the unmanaged code is a WinAPI BOOL type and not a standard C++ bool then the results will be unpredictable and this would be a bug in the program. Still, the managed type itself is blittable and will be blitted nevertheless.

Comment: Also, the "unmanaged" constraint does NOT provide any "guarantees that the bits representing the type will be correctly interpreted by the two parties." It is a guarantee that the type does not contain references at any nesting level. In other words, it is a guarantee that the type not contain managed pointers to other objects. In other words, it is a guarantee that the type can be serialized to a continuous stream of bytes. Such a type, although serialized to a continuous stream, can still be misinterpreted, for example due to wrong field types or missing/wrong MarshalAs attributes.

Comment: @ultimA Could you clarify what definition of "blittable" you are using here?  The definition I am using is in my answer.  I wonder what definition you are using.

Comment: Blittable types are types that do not get converted to another format to be marshaled to and from native code. Note that this does not depend on how the unmanaged counterpart defines the type. The important part is that no format conversions take place, not whether this was wanted by the programmer or not. Think about it: Otherwise whether the type is blittable or not would depend on programmer's intent.